# Add navigation bar on a view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

i am new on iOS and i wanna add a navigation bar on my view controller with 2 buttons back on left and subscribe on right. ive got no clue how to do it..till now i have just added a nav bar from interface builder, created a (strong)refrnce for it in .h file and did following coding.

```
 navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 1026, 50)];
[navBar setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[navBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[navBar setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
UIBarButtonItem *bi1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"subscribe" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(editBotton)];

bi1.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

bi1.tintColor =[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.305f alpha:0.0f];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = bi1;
```

but nothings happeing.. please help

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/ use this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add in AppDelegate,

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                                                 bundle: nil];
     
        SampleViewController *mainViewController = (SampleViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                           instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SampleViewController"];
     
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
     
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
        [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to learn the basic concepts about **UINavigationController**. You can learn from the below tutorials:

http://simplecode.me/2011/09/04/an-introduction-to-uinavigationcontroller/

http://www.ralfebert.de/archive/ios/tutorial_iosdev/navigationcontroller/

http://bharanijayasuri.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/simple-uinavigationcontroller-tutorial-2/