# UINavigation Controll

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

So I have made a homePage UIViewController and i wish this to be my "main view"

So in my app delegates...

```
HomePage *homepage = [[HomePage alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigator = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homepage];

navigator.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

[self.window addSubview:navigator.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I added this to a navigationController in my stroryboard  (i think this could be part of the problem)

THE Problem

My homepage has buttons and a smaller sliding view... these things do not work at all... they just exists sort of as a image/mast

When i started the project i had a UIViewController in the storyboard which i "used" to create this homepage but did not do anything on it except added a image which i do now programatically anyway.

I am now trying to remove it without breaking the whole project.
I also tested my homePage and the "viewDidLoad" was called.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Tel me what you want exactly? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316713/add-navigation-bar-on-a-view-controller/19317010#19317010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this. Replace this line

```
[self.window addSubview:navigator.view];
```

with

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigator;
```